# How to get data from mysql with a specific word?

Tags: mysql, hashtag

I am making a small social network site. People can make posts with hashtags.

Examples:

> "I hate #walking under rain"
>
> "Today i did my #homework."

When user posts these, code sends these to database as texts.

Now my question is, I want to make pages for all these hastags, for-example `example.com/walking` and in this page I want to display all posts which includes `#walking` text in it.

How can I select the data which has `#walking` in the post?

Advance Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you explain us a bit more about what is your database table design & how are you storing posts ? if you are storing as is then you can use Like operator...

Comment: I am storing the post as it is.. user_ID, date, post  in the post it writes I hate #walking under rain.

Comment: Great! You got the answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like: `select * from posts where lower(post_body) like '%#walking%';`